# Semiconductor and temperature dependence

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, temperature, semiconductor-physics

Does the conductivity of both intrinsic and extrinsic semiconductor increases with temperature or is it that conductivity of extrinsic semiconductor decreases with temperature just like a conductor ?

Comment: https://www.polytechnichub.com/temperature-effect-extrinsic-semiconductors/. This might help you.